# Reloading server in nuxt3js after Clear Cache

Tags: server, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nitro

I have clear cache in my nuxt3js application with [npx nuxi clean](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/commands/cleanup#nuxi-cleanup),  this command removes `.nuxt` ,
`.output` , `node_modules/.vite`  and `node_modules/.cache`. So inorder to run the app again I need to run `npm install` and then start the serve with `npm run dev`.

But I receive the below message without ending. Error: `Reloding server...`

[image]

How do I stop this.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer my own question after a day of research. I found out that by adding the below code in `nuxt.config.ts` solved the issue

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({

nitro: {
    esbuild: {
      options: {
        target: 'esnext'
      }
    }
  }

})
```

thereafter every thing works back to normally again.